# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal') and also in truffle console when i try to see the number of candidates it is also undefined. is there any problme with the command (.candidatesCount().toNumber)?

```
const { assert } = require("assert");


var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

contract("Election", function (acc) {
  it("initializes with two candidates", function () {
    return Election.deployed()
      .then(function (ins) {
        return ins.candidatesCount();
      })
      .then(function (count) {
        assert.equal(count, 2);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const assert = require("assert");`

Why import a name value? That's whats causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

`assert` gets exported with a default export (`module.exports = function assert() {...}`) so you need to import it accordingly.

```
const assert = require('assert');
```